# Checking if checkbox is checked or not with php class

Tags: php, validation, class

I have a class, and one of the variables is terms, for the terms and conditions.  I am having a major brain fart and can't find the answer for some reason.

```
if(empty($this->terms)) {
        $this->error .= '<li>You must agree to the terms and conditions.</li>';
    }
```

This doesn't work if the box is checked.  It will still return the error to the form if it's checked.  What's the correct syntax for this?

Thanks guys, silly question I'm sure, just escaping me

Comment: What is the var_dump of $this->terms? In both checked and unchecked conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the checkbox is coming from an html form, you can use isset() to determine if it's checked.

```
if(isset($_POST['terms']))
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, for some reason forgot it... here's what I ended up with for others with the same problem.

if(!isset($_POST['terms'])) {
   $this->error .= '<li>You must agree to the terms and conditions.</li>';
  }